# Split float into integer and decimals in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I have a float like 3.75, how can I split it into the integer 3 and the float 0.75?

Do I have to convert the float into a string, and then split the string by ".", and then convert the parts into integers and floats again, or is there a more elegant or "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned you can use `3.75.to_i` to get the integer.
An alternate way to get the remainder is using the `%` operator eg.
`3.75 % 1`

Answer (score 25):

You can use [Numeric#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) with argument `1` for this:

> Returns an array containing the quotient and modulus obtained by dividing num by numeric.

```
a.divmod 1
=> [3, 0.75]
```

If you want to get precise value, this method is available for [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) as well:

```
3.456.divmod 1
=> [3, 0.45599999999999996]

require 'bigdecimal'
div_mod = BigDecimal("3.456").divmod 1
[div_mod[0].to_i, div_mod[1].to_f]
=> [3, 0.456]
```

Comment: +1, I was not familiar with this method.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that this solution differs from the accepted solution for negative numbers. `-3.75.to_i #=> -3`, and yet `-3.75.divmod 1 #=> [-4, 0.25]`

Answer (score 0):

puts "frac = #{(3.456).to_s.split(".").last.prepend("0.").to_f}"
puts "Integer part = #{(3.456).truncate}"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).