# How can I strip the decimal point and everything after it in a float?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I print only the non decimal numbers of a float? By that I mean everything before the decimal point. `@float.round(0)` doesn't work, because that rounds the number. I want to simply strip the decimal point and everything after it.

For example, 599.9999 should be printed "599".

I also can't do `<%= @float.chars.first.to_s + @float.chars.second.to_s + ...` because it is unsure how long the float is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `to_integer` method in Ruby to strip the integer part of the float:

```
>123.434343.to_i
>123
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html

Just found it already answered in a similar question:

[Split float into integer and decimals in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173696/split-float-into-integer-and-decimals-in-ruby)

Comment: It isn't necessary to say "Edit:". We can tell what was changed and when. Instead, simply add the content into the answer naturally.

Answer (score 2):

@float.truncate should do the job. Same functionality as to_i and to_int.

Comment: Mention your suggestion in question comment.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it'd be a comment. If you want it to be an answer show why that works and make it a statement not a question back to the OP.

Comment: Noted and edited as a statement.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, just do:

```
599.9999.to_i
```